# Equilateral triangle equivalent condition

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with centroid $G$ . Let it also have the property that given any $M$ on (non-extended) $BC$ there are points $N,P$ on $AB,AC$ respectively such that $G$ is the incenter of triangle $MNP$ .
Is it true that $ABC$ is equilateral ?